# Autoplay/loop Functionality on mobile (HTML5 Website)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have added an autoplay/loop functionality to my Vimeo video; but is not working on mobile (HTML5 Website). Do you know if it's not supported on mobile devices or is there a code genius that could help me out?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536858/video-js-autoplay-and-loop-not-working-on-phone) if refers to something usefull for your case

Comment: Would help a lot if we could see your code.